# Cannot retrieve desired data in Unity from MySQL server

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unity-game-engine, scripting

I have the following C# code:

```
public class DataLoader : MonoBehaviour {

    IEnumerator Start (){
        WWW data = new WWW ("http://a7h1.byethost6.com/sample.php");
        yield return data;
        string strData = data.text;
        Debug.Log (strData);
    }
}
```

The output from the url http://a7h1.byethost6.com/sample.php is this:

> Name:juan,Name:john,

I have attached this C# script to my main camera. When it executes it prints the following:

> > function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return
> >     e}function toHex(){for(var
> >     d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;fd[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return
> >     e.toLowerCase()}var
> >     a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("d141c35148277e598226388d8d5d6e0d");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+";
> >     expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
> >     document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer);
> >     location.href="http://a7h1.byethost6.com/sample.php?ckattempt=1";This
> >     site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your
> >     browser or use a browser with Javascript
> >     support UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
> >     c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/DataLoader.cs:14)

Comment: What is desired result?

Comment: Name:juan,Name:john,

Comment: Do you have access to sample.php file? I think problem may be in that file.

Comment: Yes, you can view it yourself here  http://a7h1.byethost6.com/sample.php

Comment: You should create a separate service for this, which will return your desired data instead of whole page, then fetch it through query string

Comment: @jeanl no, all I can see is result of that php script, not script itself. And in that script can be code which causes good behavior in browser with JavaScript and redirecting, but false behavior without it. Because response you get in Unity is HTML code to create cookie and navigate to same page using new get parameter and created cookie.

Comment: Your best call would be that the php method returns a json file containing those values.